# What is the difference between std::ranges::begin and std::begin?

Tags: c++, range, c++20, std-ranges

What is the difference between [`std::begin`](https://eel.is/c++draft/iterator.range) and the new [`std::ranges::begin`](https://eel.is/c++draft/range.access#begin)? (same for `end`, `size`, etc.)

Both seem to work identically:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <ranges>

template<std::ranges::range R>
void printInfo(const R &range)
{
    std::cout << (std::ranges::begin(range) == std::begin(range));
}

template<class T>
struct X
{
    std::vector<T> v;

    auto begin() const { return v.begin(); }
    auto end() const { return v.end(); }
};

int main()
{
    printInfo(std::vector{1, 2, 3, 4});
    printInfo(std::array{1, 2, 3, 4});
    printInfo(X<int>{{1, 2, 3, 4}});

    int oldSchool[]{1, 2, 3, 4};
    printInfo(oldSchool);
}
```

Compiles and prints `1111`, as expected.

Does `ranges::begin` make `std::begin` obsolete? Or do the two have different use-cases?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

There are a few differences.

First, `ranges::begin(x)` works on all ranges while `std::begin(x)` does not. The latter will not do ADL lookup on `begin`, so ranges specified like:

```
struct R {
    ...
};
auto begin(R const&);
auto end(R const&);
```

won't work, which is why you have to write something like:

```
using std::begin, std::end;
auto it = begin(r);
```

You don't have to do that two-step with `ranges::begin`.

Second, `ranges::begin(x)` is a little safer. Ranges introduces this notion of a *borrowed range*, which is a range whose iterators that you can hold onto safely. `vector<int>` for instance is *not* a borrowed range - since once the `vector` dies the data dies. `ranges::begin` guards against that:

```
auto get_data() -> std::vector<int>;

auto a = std::begin(get_data());    // ok, but now we have a dangling iterator
auto b = ranges::begin(get_data()); // ill-formed
```

Third, `ranges::begin` and `ranges::end` have extra type checks. `ranges::begin(r)` requires the result of either `r.begin()` or `begin(r)` to model `input_or_output_iterator`. `ranges::end(r)` requires `ranges::begin(r)` to be valid and requires either `r.end()` or `end(r)` to model `sentinel_for<decltype(ranges::begin(r))>`. That is - that whatever we get from `begin` and `end` is *actually* a range.

This means that, for instance:

```
struct X {
    int begin() const { return 42; }
};

X x;
auto a = std::begin(x);    // ok, a == 42
auto b = ranges::begin(x); // ill-formed, int is not an iterator
```

Although more annoyingly is a case where you have an iterator type that might be incrementable, dereferenceable, comparable, etc... but fail to have a default constructor. That does not meet the requirements of C++20's [`input_or_output_iterator`](https://eel.is/c++draft/iterator.concept.iterator) so `ranges::begin` will fail.

Fourth, `ranges::begin` is a function object, while `std::begin` is a set of overloaded function templates:

```
auto f = ranges::begin; // ok
auto g = std::begin;    // error: which std::begin did you want?
```

Fifth, some of the ranges customization point objects have other fallback behavior besides just calling a function of that name. `std::size(r)` always invokes a function named `size` (unless `r` is a raw array). `std::empty(r)` always invokes a function named `empty`(unless `r` is a raw array, in which case it's just `false`, or `r` is an `initializer_list`, in which case `r.size() == 0`). But `ranges::size` could [under certain circumstances](http://eel.is/c++draft/range.prim.size#2) perform `ranges::end(r) - ranges::begin(r)` (as a fallback if `size(r)` and `r.size()` don't exist) just like `ranges::empty` could [under certain circumstances](https://eel.is/c++draft/range.access#range.prim.empty-2) either do `ranges::size(r) == 0` or `ranges::begin(r) == ranges::end(r)`.

Comment: It's always a pleasure to read about all the under-the-hood stuff happening in ranges v3.

Comment: So `ranges::begin`, etc does make `std::begin` obsolete? Or are there cases where one still must use `std::begin` instead of `ranges::begin`?

Comment: @cigien Well, if your iterators aren't default constructible or lack postfix increment or something, then `ranges::begin` will reject them due to those extra type checks.

Comment: Aah, ok, and I'm assuming that iterators like that are valid? and not breaking any other rules?

Comment: @cigien Depends on how you define "valid." They're not valid C++20 `input_or_output_iterator`s if they're not default constructible.

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive answer! So if I understand it correctly there would generally be no reason to use `std::begin` in new code, right?
But then maybe we could take it a step further and also never use `.begin()` because `ranges::begin` has the borrowed range check, or would that be silly? (Also unfortunately it's much more verbose; something which C++ seems to be 'good' at sometimes)